# Is C++ STL a C++ API?

Tags: c++, api, c++11

We have an assignment wherein we have been forbidden to use any C++ API.  So, this brings me to the following questions:

1. What exactly is the difference between a library and an API?
2. Is the C++ STL (http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/table_of_contents.html) considered a C++ API?
3. Next time onwards, how do I identify whether I am using a library or an API?

Thanks!

P.S:  I understand my instructor can let me know whether we can use STL, but I wanted to know the difference between the libraries and the APIs irrespective of his answer; hence the question.

Comment: Rather use http://en.cppreference.com/w/ as the C++ STL reference

Comment: @iksemyonov, thanks for the link!  I will refer that as well.

Comment: @iksemyonov That is a C++ standard library reference. The SGI stuff is actually a true STL reference.

Comment: @juanchopanza how up-to-date is the SGI website, what version of the standard?

Comment: @iksemyonov It isn't "the standard" C++ library, it is the STL. I don't know how well it overlaps with the standard library these days.

Comment: I say tomato, you say tomato.

Comment: Once you create a function or a set of functions possibly dealing with a certain class of problem in a (more or less) reusable manner, you kind of create an API (application program interface). So to be absolutely sure you do not violate your instructors requirements, best do not write any functions at all and do it all in ``main()`` :)

Comment: @BitTickler, thank you.  So what about using the `#include`s?  Ideally, even that should be left out, no?

Comment: You cannot write C++ without using the C++ Standard Library (knowingly or not). Since the library is exposed through an API, that requirement is meaningless (unless it is meant to read: Use any programming language except C++).

Comment: @juanchopanza yes I'm aware of the difference, but the STL keeps evolving too with the new versions of the standard, doesn't it?

Comment: @IInspectable Care to elaborate? It is very possible to write a program without including any headers. If you use built-in features of C++,  such as variables and conditional statements, you are not using an API. We don't even know what kind of assignment OP has; what if he only needs to write a function that takes input and returns output?

Comment: @Ville-ValtteriTiittanen: There are lots of things, that are implemented in the support libraries, without you even noticing. Take initialization of globals, for example. Or a `dynamic_cast` to reference type. No header file included, but suddenly your code starts throwing `std::bad_cast` exceptions. It's pretty challenging to write a non-trivial C++ program that doesn't use any libraries at all.

Comment: @IInspectable You can avoid using C++ specific header files, especially STL etc. and still program C++. Fun story. In an embedded product of ours years ago I used STL and had problems right when I noticed that the customer ran 3 (!!) versions of STL on their system: Dinkum, In-house-modified and SGI. So, after learning that sad lesson I removed all STL dependencies, created my own little set of data structures I needed and lived happily ever after.

Comment: @BitTickler "created my own little set of data structures I needed". :) Oh, wow! I assume your code is not an c++ API, so can you make it public  for others to use when someone with authority forbids them to use an API? :)

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi The business was such that the same set of functionality was sold to customers using various embedded platforms and operating systems. Think "middleware". We had no control on how they build rest of their system and so it was most time efficient (porting to their environment) if our code had as little as possible dependencies. The data structures I used in my code were not part of the API the customer was shown. It was implementation...

Comment: You need to ask your tutor. My view is that no, it's not an API ,since the c++ language cannot function fully without it (see documentation of typeid, cout, etc). Even printf is part of the c++ standard library (which encapsulates most of the c standard library), so excluding use of the stl prevents you from printing any results in a portable way.

Comment: @RichardHodges And yet, maybe all the instructor wanted might have been to ``#include <stdint.h>`` rather than ``#include <cstdint>`` etc. Maybe he wanted "old fashioned C with objects style rather than over the roof C++ template madness" ;)

Comment: @BitTickler `#include <stdint.h>` would be C, not c++. And it's still an API. And still does not facilitate I/O. 17.6.1.2 mandates that the C features of this header are to be made available through `#include <cstdint>` and that they are to be in the `std` namespace. Again, relying on the types therein being in the global namespace results in an incorrect program.

Comment: @RichardHodges On a circumstantial base, I doubt that. Before ``cstdint`` etc. were introduced, it was **legal** c++ to include ``stdint.h``. And C++ is so proud about not breaking old code. Your statement suggests, that this was a breaking change, then?

Comment: @BitTickler you're right. Annex D.5 mentions the C standard headers. They are valid but deprecated.

Comment: @BitTickler: The C++ support libraries aren't just a set of header files that you can use, or leave out. This is much more involved. C++ exception handling is often implemented in part in the compiler and in part in the library. You cannot just 'remove' that. As I pointed out, omitting C++ headers doesn't make your code C++ free (remember that `dynamic_cast` example?).

Comment: @IInspectable From what you state above, it could be concluded that there existed a set of mandatory headers every program is compelled to include. Which are those? :)

Comment: @BitTickler: You don't have to include **any** headers to use a `dynamic_cast`, and yet, you are already using exceptions. You cannot avoid using library code by omitting an `#include` directive. It's part of the language, and you are using it. And this is not the only library feature you are using, without any `#include` directives. It was just the first that came to mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[API (Application programming interface)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_programming_interface) is the interface of a library. To use a library, you call functions in its API. So you are not allowed to use any library.

Difference of library and API:

- An API is the interface. You include a header file that belongs to library, and it has declarations of functions. Those declarations, that header file, they are the API.
- A library consists of both API, and the actual implementation of those functions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Could you please elaborate - *To use a library, you call functions in its API* - what is an API?

Comment: @user6490375 An API is the interface. You include a header file that belongs to library, and it has declarations of functions. Those declarations, that header file, they are the API. A library consists of both API, and the actual implementation of those functions.

Comment: So in that case, when I write `#include<cstdio>`, am I still using some API?

Comment: @user6490375 Yes, you are using API of C++ standard library. From the Wikipedia link: "C++ Standard Template Library, [..] are examples of different forms of APIs."

Comment: @user6490375 `<cstdio>` is a C++ wrapper of a C header `<stdio.h>`, so I think it's not the best example for a "C++ API". I'd rather call it wrapped C API.